# Как вывести не объекты?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

была дана задача Дан массив строк mas. Одной строкой создайте словарь, в котором по ключу строки будет записана пара (кортеж длины 2) (индекс строки в массиве mas, длина строки)
1. Правильно ли мое решение:

```
d = {(k for k in mas): zip((mas.index(i) for i in mas), (len(i) for i in mas))}
```

если нет, то пожалуйста не пишите полностью верное решение, а скажите в верном ли я направлении двигаюсь.

Если оно все же верно, то как вывести ключи и значения?
Пытался сделать так:`print(list(d.keys()), list(d.values()))`
Но вывод был таков:

```
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000017B0F2B6390>] [<zip object at 0x0000017B0F2AD9C8>]
```

Comment: *>как вывести ключи и значения* - например, `print(*d.items(), sep="\n")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mas = ('55','retter','rthfg','qw','ddfd','cvb','cvbc')

d = {v:(i, len(v)) for i, v in enumerate(mas)}
```

Answer (score 1):

я правильно понимаю? дано mas = ('55','666') должно получиться d = {'55': (0,2), '666': (1,3)}

```
mas = ('55','retter','rthfg','qw','ddfd','cvb','cvbc')

d = {k: (mas.index(y), len(y)) for k, y in zip(mas, mas)}
```